# To break looping while creating nested Groups in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have functionality in my project in which we are making groups and child groups. But, here child group are having high priority from parent.

```
eg. A (parent) -> B(child) -> C(sub child) 

B is associated with A
C is associated with B
```

In the next step, its possible I can associate with A. But, it will create loop which I need to break. Here, above C is having highest priority can access B(data) and A(Data) as well and B with second priority and has access with A(Data).

My Db structure:

```
Group table
------------------------------------------
id     name    parentId
------------------------------------------
1       A        null
2       B         1
3       C         2
-------------------------------------------

Group_Data Table
--------------------------------------
gd_id       grp_id      Data
--------------------------------------
11             1         Peter
22             2         Dennis
33             3         Jene
----------------------------------------
```

So when i access and try to accosiate Group A with parent as C then it should not allow me.
I want to write sql query for this.
Please help me out of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create following mysql function to get all the Ancestry

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetGroupAncestry` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetGroupAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;

    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(parentId,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT parentId FROM Group WHERE id = ch) A;

        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN rv;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Using this you can set condition in you server side language as well as in you query by using it as derived table.